# CasperJS captureSelector does not capture selector, captures whole page

Tags: google-analytics, casperjs

I have a dashboard in Google Analytics.
I want to only capture a certain part of the dashboard using [CasperJS](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector).

No matter what I've tried it captures the entire page.

**What I'm I doing wrong here?**

This is the HTML hierarchy that I find when I inspect the Google Analytics dashboard:

```
<div id="ID-view">
    <div class="_GAeH" id="ID-dashboard">
       <div id="ID-layout">
          <div class="_GARW ">
             <div class="_GAoA">
                <!-- more <div>s with the content -->
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CasperJS code snippet:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://www.google.com/analytics/web/the/rest/of/the/url/', function() {
    this.fill('form#gaia_loginform', { 'Email': 'user', 'Passwd':'pass' }, true);
});

casper.waitForSelector('.ID-row-4-0-0', function() {
    casper.page.paperSize = {
        height: '11in',
        width: '8.5in',
        orientation:'portrait',
        border: '0.4in'
    };

// NONE of these work the way I think they should
// this.captureSelector('ga.pdf','#ID-view');
// this.captureSelector('ga.pdf','#ID-dashboard');
// this.captureSelector('ga.pdf','#ID-layout');
this.captureSelector('ga.pdf','._GAoA');
// this.captureSelector('ga.pdf','._GARW'); // <-- this one fails, capture height is messed up
},
function() {
    this.echo("Timeout reached");
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I give.....after many hours of trying to figure this out, with output as PDF, I found that there seems to be an issue in PhantomJS that hasn't been fixed in over 2 years. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10465

Comment: The [currently last comment](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10465#issuecomment-36969179) suggests overflow and iframes. Have you tried it? Would be nice if you could provide an answer.

Comment: I have no answer. I'm giving up on this Casper idea and am going to try a different idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.captureSelector('ga.pdf','div._GAoA', {quality: 100});
```

If you cant take the screenshot of the element _GAoA please share the output of your casperjs scrpit.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I totally gave up on this particular idea and went another direction